# django_extensions не дает запустить локальный сервер Django через конфигурацию в pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

буду очень признателен, если найдет ответ на мой вопрос.

Появилась проблема, в которой хочу разобраться.
В моем проекте в папке settings.py подключен django_extensions:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django_extensions',
'movie_app',
```

]

Я создаю конфигурацию в pycharm для запуска сервера, пытаюсь ее запустить, но мне выдает ошибку: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_extensions'

*Исправлено*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*Исправлено*

Если же я запускаю сервер через команду manage.py runserver в терминале, то всё работает. Также всё через запуск конфигурации, если удалить в INSTALLED_APPS  django_extensions.

При этом использовав pip freeze я отчетливо вижу, что django-extensions установлен:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да можно заметить, что названия различаются, установлен django-extensions, а в INSTALLED_APPS я указываю django_extensions(разница в нижнем подчеркивании и тире). Но в видеоуроке на степике, по которому я и учусь, просят именно таким образом использовать django_extensions. Но даже если указать в INSTALLED_APPS - django-extensions(стоит тире), то все-равно будет появляться ошибка.

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема. Я могу, конечно, и постоянно запускать сервер через терминал, но мне хотелось бы узнать, почему с установленным django_extensions я не могу запускать сервер через конфигурацию в Pycharm.

Полная запись ошибки, на всякий случай:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Меня смущает, что на скриншоте с pip freeze у вас стоит путь `C:\MyProjectDjango\Django_egoroff\movie_proj`, а в настройке `Python interpreter` виртуальное окружение находится по совершенно другому пути `C:\Рабочее\Всякое\python work pycharm\Django_egoroff\movie_proj`

Comment: Согласен, это моя ошибка при написании вопроса. Я не заметил ошибки на скриншоте, но я исправил. Но даже при правильном указании виртуального окружения, проблема сохраняется

Comment: А pip freeze в каком виртуальном окружении запускается? На скриншоте этого не видно, где и как вы его активировали?

Comment: В виртуальном окружении проекта

Comment: Каком конкретно? Как активировали?